# Graphics + Archiving

Tags: jmh

I have 2 questions about JMH:

1) How can I generate graphics from the output. I know I can output to csv/json and I know I can set up something myself. But would be nice if I didn't need to do it myself.

2) Is there some out of the box archiving functionality so that I can e.g. make performance comparisons over time for e.g. trend analysis. Or could compare the performance between different git branches. It looks so far this functionality doesn't exist and I need to come up with something myself.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, JMH follows the Unix philosophy -- "does one thing, and does it well" -- provides the reliable benchmarking environment. It already bundles the human-readable output for ad-hoc uses. Users wanting advanced reporting, results storage, etc. need to offload this work to some other tools (R+ggplot2, gnuplot and other renderers of choice are mostly used).